# Someone uses my service to spam people with sms. How to deal with this?

Tags: spam, sms

Every time when user wants to login to my service it sends one time password (OTP) to the user's phone number, then this OTP is used to confirm login.

Someone uses my service to bombard people with sms notifications.

I already implemented various blocks:

- no more then 1 OTP per phone number per minute
- no more then 5 OTP per IP per minute

What else can I do? Will captcha work?

Comment: Do you already check if the number provided does not belong to some premium-rate telephone number?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to solve the problem, you could **kill** the problem.
SMS is no longer considered secure anyway, at least for sensitive functions.

Ditch SMS and offer your customers a choice of 2FA solutions available on the market today. Most people have a smartphone but for those who don't, you may still keep SMS OTP. And then, in this scenario you could consider captcha as a mitigation technique. The point is, not every account has to be enabled for SMS. You can provide alternatives.

The fact that spammers are able to trigger SMS storms means they already have some information like a username perhaps. Is there anything you can do to address this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the use of dynamic IP address blocking - I have a good amount of success with the following two free services:

- https://sigs.interserver.net/ipslim.txt
- https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/blacklist *this one requires the use of an api key, and update frequency is limited to four per 24hr period*

The following command uses `curl` to connect to the AbuseIPDB, authenticate with the account token, and then download the result, with various parameters set according to the [API documentation](https://docs.abuseipdb.com/#blacklist-endpoint)

```
curl --fail --write-out '\nCURL_%{http_code}+'$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S') --silent --tlsv1.2 -H "Key: 7d467ef655e91e7db69f2078df1b0c2ccefb8eedc0372e9187b0d211aa1f336b73271e145f12aebc" -H "Accept: text/plain" -d countMinimum=15 -d maxAgeInDays=5 -d confidenceMinimum=90 -G https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/blacklist
```

I access these services periodically, to extract the contents in the database, and create blocked ip address records as files within a tiered directory structure on the file-system: `/OCTET1/OCTET1.OCTET2/IP4ADDR` (dotted decimal). If the entry already exists, I `touch` the file again to update the metadata. Over time, this builds into a useful database.

*Note to self: edit this answer to include the bash commands that prevent unbounded growth of the blocked ip files db...*

In the context of Litespeed webserver running on Cloudlinux, I use `.htaccess` files to check to see if the remote ip address exists in a file on the file-system (representing a blocked address).

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr  '([0-9]{1,3})\.'              USR_RADDR_ONE=$1
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr  '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})'    USR_RADDR_TWO=$1

ErrorDocument 410 'Your IP address exists in an automated blacklist: connection refused.'
RewriteCond /etc/._ipblock_rbl/%{ENV:USR_RADDR_ONE}/%{ENV:USR_RADDR_ONE}/%{REMOTE_ADDR} -f 
RewriteRule ^ /e410_deny_%{ENV:USR_RADDR_TWO} [G]
```

I can't take credit for this idea, which stops about 50% of our traffic at the gate, and hasn't resulted in a single complaint to request unblocking, in nearly two years of production use. *I wish I could find the reference to the source, a European(?) German(?) author of a `.htaccess` help site ?? If anyone knows, could you please edit or comment? thanks!*